# POST not implemented

Tags: openlayers-2, wps, geoexplorer

I'm developing a client wps modifying the example WPSDemo.js from 
http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/processing/wpsclient/index.html .
I'm using zoo-project as WPS server.
I'm trying to invoke the "buffer" process implemented in GRASS GIS gives me the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:9080/proxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcgi-bin%2Fzoo_loader.cgi%3F 501 (Not Implemented)
```

The query POST is:

```
<wps:Execute xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">v_buffer</ows:Identifier>
<wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">input</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Or data source for direct OGR access</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/xml"><![CDATA[<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"><gml:featureMember xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><feature:features xmlns:feature="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" fid="OpenLayers_Feature_Vector_248"><feature:geometry><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-6383273.5489707,1396657.4552779 -4230806.8327598,26905.908598173 -6246298.3943028,-442723.19312058 -6383273.5489707,1396657.4552779</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></feature:geometry></feature:features></gml:featureMember></wfs:FeatureCollection>]]></wps:ComplexData>
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">layer</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">A single vector map can be connected to multiple database tables. This number determines which table to use. When used with direct OGR access this is the layer name.</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">cats</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Example: 1,3,7-9,13</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">where</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Example: income  1000 and inhab :: 10000</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">type</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Feature type</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">distance</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Buffer distance along major axis in map units</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData>195678.7923828125</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">minordistance</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Buffer distance along minor axis in map units</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">angle</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Angle of major axis in degrees</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">bufcolumn</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Name of column to use for buffer distances</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">scale</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Scaling factor for attribute column values</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">tolerance</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Maximum distance between theoretical arc and polygon segments as multiple of buffer</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">-s</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Make outside corners straight</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">-c</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Dont make caps at the ends of polylines</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">-t</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">Transfer categories and attributes</ows:Title>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData />
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
</wps:DataInputs>
<wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml">
        <ows:Identifier xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">output</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
</wps:ResponseForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding values for each input you included in your POST request. For instance, if your `layer` input should not have any value set, as it is the case in the sample POST request you quoted, then remove it from the input list in your request. Obviously, you should take care to give the minimal required inputs to make the service working properly.